# What Hook/Action is performed when a field in checkout form is changed in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

I have added a custom field in WooCommerce checkout like below:

```
function oc_add_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping_sub_area'] = array(
        'label'    => __( 'Sub Area' ),
        'type'     => 'select',
        'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'priority' => 68,
        'required' => true,
        'id'       => 'th_sub_area',
        'options'  => array(
            ''        =>'Select',
            'Clifton' => 'Clifton1', 
            'DHA'     => 'DHA1',
        ),
        'custom_attributes' => array(),
        'validate'          => array(),
        'default'           => '',
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'oc_add_checkout_fields' );
```

When this field is changed, a pre loader is shown on the your order section in checkout form.
I want to perform following: If selected value in above field is Clifton1 then add shipping charges 100 to  the cart else add shipping charges 300 to the cart,

I have tried different hooks and actions but I am unable to get the value of custom added field inside the hook. For example I have used following filter:

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages( $array ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    //die('I am hre');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    return $array; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 10, 1 );
```

In `$array`, I am getting:

```
[destination] => Array
    (
        [country] => PK
        [state] => TA
        [postcode] => 
        [city] => fds
        [address] => fsdf
        [address_1] => fsdf
        [address_2] => fsd
    )
```

But I am not getting value of `shipping_sub_area` or `th_sub_area`.

Comment: This is something much more complicated that requires jQuery and Ajax… Also you should rename your field simply `sub_area`, as Woocommerce prepend "billing_" to it, on billing section and "shipping_" on shipping section… You need to do something like on [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160586/3730754) for example…

Comment: Hello
Ajax or on change event on field is already firing as i have `update_totals_on_change` class on the element. 
For field name, i already have `shipping_` added in field name. th_sub_area is just the HTML ID used in DOM. 
I need hook or filter that is fired when a field is changed, Thank you

Comment: Ok.. Than plz provide guidelines. I have drop down field value in ajax call back. plz help me on how can i pass the value to 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' action

Comment: You need to use something like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160586/3730754 targeting in jQuery your dropdown on "blur" event to trigger an ajax request… So try yourself, update your question with the code that you tried…

Comment: thank @LoicTheAztec This helped a lot. My work  has done.. Thank you

Comment: Mostly for Woocommerce tagged questions, the right place is StackOverFlow…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ajax to set values in WooCommerce session variables first. Once your values are set in wc()->session, then you can access them anywhere within the WooCommerce hooks or actions.

See below code example:

```
/*Ajax Call Back*/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

$shipping_charges;
function my_action_callback() {
    $shipping_charges =  $_POST['shipping_charges'];
    WC()->session->set("th_shipping_charges", $shipping_charges );
}

/*Ajax code to get values from the form and post to Wordpress backend*/

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_footer_code' );

function my_footer_code() { 
$html='
    jQuery("#th_sub_area").change(function(){
    var shipping_charges;
        var selected_sub_area = jQuery("#th_sub_area").find(":selected").val();
        if(selected_sub_area='DHA'){
               var shipping_charges= 150; 
        }

       / In front end of WordPress we have to define ajaxurl /  
       var ajaxurl = "'.admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'";

       var data = {
         "action": "my_action",
       "shipping_charges" : shipping_charges,
                };

                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    jQuery("body").trigger("update_checkout");
                });
    });
';
echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Hello rizwan. this approach worked fine for me. Thank you